# Issue while printing variables using echo

Tags: shell

I have an issue printing two variables using echo. Below is the code snippet from the script:-

```
tdaydatefile=$(date +'%m%d%Y')
ip=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}')
echo "Dumping all network connections to $HOME/MyLog/netstat_$ip_$tdaydatefile.csv!"
```

When the script is run, it only prints below:-

```
Dumping all network connections to /root/MyLog/netstat_12022014.csv!
```

It doesn't print the ip address (ip variable) of the system. If I replace ip with tdaydatefile in echo, it prints ip and ignores tdaydatefile variable.

Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: `ip_` is a valid variable name,s o you're dumping an undefined variable. try `{$ip}`, or switch to using dashes, `...-$ip-$tday` instead.

Comment: You should tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: @MarcB: I think you mean `netstat_${ip}_$tdaydatefile` where the open brace goes after the $ and before the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Since **`_`** is a valid variable-name character, you need to tell the shell where your variable name ends. (In your code, the shell interprets `ip_` as the variable name.)

This can be done by enclosing the variable name in `{...}`, i.e., use `${ip}` in this case:

```sh
echo "Dumping all network connections to $HOME/MyLog/netstat_${ip}_$tdaydatefile.csv!"
```

Note that it's not necessary with `$HOME` or `$tdaydatefile` , because `/` and `.` are not a valid variable-name chars.

When in doubt, however, use `${...}` — it also helps readability.

Comment: The local coding convention at the office is "all variable name references always enclosed in `${name}`".  I'm not wholly keen on it, but it is systematic and can be fixed automatically.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Personally, I only do it when technically necessary and for readability in expanding strings, because the curly braces are awkward to type. Re your edit: while probably not needed in such a short answer, I find bolding key passages useful to quickly draw attention to the *gist* of a post; it's a technique I use when creating notes for personal use as well.

Comment: Style is complex.  I mostly use `$variable` rather than `${variable}` in my own code, but there is some wisdom in the rule imposed at work.  Answer formatting style is likewise complex, but keeping bold to a minimum is generally a good idea -- but also very subjective.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the feedback; agreed. A final thought on bolding: The full narrative benefits beginners, whereas the bolded passages help the more experienced / return viewers get the gist more quickly.